# Reactive Api for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, reactive-programming

I want speed up Elasticsearch with reactive paradigm. I see that Elasticsearch provide reactive rest API [for example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html#java-rest-high-document-bulk-async).
I will happy to use something like spring-data.
I find reactive repositories for MongoDB, Redis, Couchbase and many others, but not for Elasticsearch.

Exists any reason why it's not implemented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Spring supports [Reactive Elasticsearch Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)

You can use `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` or `ReactiveCrudRepository`